# PC not working as it should after inserting more RAM

Tags: ubuntu, memory, motherboard

My PC is an ASUS TUF FX10CP.

It came with 8 GB RAM preinstalled. This Christmas, I got another 8 GB RAM stick. I inserted it into my PC, but then unusual things happened: There was no delay when pressing the power button (it had a delay before), keyboard and mouse would not light up, and after pulling out the RAM stick, same thing happened. I have tried placing 1 stick in any of the slots, but nothing happened. The motherboard has 2 slots.

After trying to turn on my PC, nothing shown up, but everything seemed like normal, although there was nothing on the screen
I tried doing Ctrl+Alt+T and executing a command that plays audio, but nothing happened
At one point it worked, but then it didn't after a restart

UPDATE: My PC works, but there is no video output
The PC works fine, but I cannot view things I type in the terminal for example

I need to do something about this, because I might lose important work.

The RAM sticks I have are these
The one on the top is the one that came with the PC.
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

[image]

Comment: Evidently the new RAM is wrong. We need the exact model of the old and new sticks to go on.

Comment: You will be fine.  Don't panic.  The WORST CASE is to pull the drive and recover the data elsewhere (which is unlikely).  Listen to @harrymc .. we can't GUESS what stuff you actually have.

Comment: I added an image with the RAM sticks

Comment: Your image is huge but of very bad quality - the text is blurred.

Comment: Sorry, but my phone won't make a photo with a better quality

Comment: Is it possible you dislodged or disconnected a cable or some other component in your PC when you added the memory?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try.
1 Reinsert your original memory stick into the original slot.
Make sure the stick facing the correct way, there are notches in the stick and tabs in slot that have to line up.
Make sure the tabs on the sides snap into the edge of the stick.

Pressing down with your fingers on the top edge of the stick may not be enough pressure to snap the tabs in. You may have to push on the stick and the tab at the same time.

Power on. If the Power on screen show(E. F1 for BIOS F12 for Boot Menu) and the OS boots then Shutdown and do the same for the 2nd stick in the SAME coloured slot on the board.

If nothing happens then you will need someone familiar with that motherboard to look at it.

PS It was not clear from your question if the OS booted and your Mouse and Keyboard did not light up or you OS did not load at all.  What was displayed on the screen right after power up.

Comment: I edited my question so more info is there. I'll try what you said

Comment: I followed your first step. It works, but there is nothing on the screen. I know it works because I tried running spd-say